# Changing controls dynamically by clicking wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to implement a certain behaviour in WPF. I searched around for quiet a long time and decided to sort the help. I want to attain the following behaviour.

I have a `TextBlock` and a `ComboBox` lying on top of each other. I want the `ComboBox` to appear when the `TextBlock` is being focused. Also once the works with `ComboBox` are finished (e.g. `ComboBoxItem` is selected). I want to get back to my older view (i.e. the `TextBlock` on top). Can anybody show a sample of this behaviour or just guide me with something.

I have a ZIndex method which I have tried as below.

```
<Grid>  
    <Button Name="Button1" Canvas.ZIndex="4" Content="Button1" Canvas.Top="100" Width="163" Height="58" FontSize="26" Click="Button1_Click" />  
    <Button Name="Button2" Canvas.ZIndex="3" Content="Button2" Canvas.Top="100" Canvas.Left="130" Width="163" Height="58" FontSize="26" Click="Button2_Click"  />
</Grid>
```

And the code behind

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Canvas.SetZIndex(sender as UIElement, 1);
}
private void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Canvas.SetZIndex(sender as UIElement, 0);
}
```

Comment: `Visibility` property, changed on selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if i correctly undestand your need exactly but this is what i think  you want:

XAML:

```
        <Grid Width="50">
            <ComboBox x:Name="cb" SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding MyObservableCollection}"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="tb" Text="{Binding ElementName=cb,Path=SelectedItem}">
                <TextBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=tb, Path=IsFocused}" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBox.Style>
            </TextBox>
        </Grid>
```

DataContext:

```
    private ObservableCollection<string> myObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>{ "one", "two", "tree" };

    public ObservableCollection<string> MyObservableCollection
    {
        get => this.myObservableCollection;
        set => SetField(ref this.myObservableCollection, value);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Denis for the answer. I have made small changes. But it gave me a good starting point.